Complex Integral of $\frac{z}{\sinh^2 z}$
I'm trying to evaluate the integral of
$$I=\int_{C}\frac{z}{(\sinh z) ^2} \ dz$$
where $C$ is the circle |z|=1.
So by Residue Theorem,
$$I = 2\pi i\mathrm{Res}(f,0).$$
This function $$f(z)=\frac{z}{\sinh^2 z}$$ has only one pole at $z=0$, so $Res(f,0)=\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} zf(z)$. Expanding $sinhz = z+ \frac{z^3}{3!}+..$ I have $$zf(z)= \frac{z^2}{\sinh^2 z}=\frac{z^2}{(z+ \frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}..)^2} = \frac{1}{(1+ \frac{z}{3!}+\frac{z^3}{5!}..)^2}$$ The limit of the last fraction $\lim_{z \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{(1+ \frac{z}{3!}+\frac{z^3}{5!}..)^2}=1$. Thus the integral I'm looking for is $2πi$.
Is there any other (simpler) way to find this, that does not need the expansion of $\sinh z$?

$\frac{\sinh z}z=\frac12\left(\frac{e^z-1}z+\frac{e^{-z}-1}{-z}\right)$

L'Hopital for $z/\sinh z$, then square the result.

How can I take the square (?) since z is first order in the nominator?

With a single pole at $z=0$ you may take the contour as a circle however small
$$\lim _{r\to 0} \ \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{  r e^{i  \phi} \ i\ r  e^{i  \phi} \ d\phi}
{\sinh^2( r e^{i  \ \phi  })}\quad \asymp \lim _{r\to 0} \ 
 \quad\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{ i \ r^2 e^{2 i  \phi} \  \ d\phi}{ 
r^2 e^{2 \ e^{i  \ \phi }}+O(r^4)} = 2\ \pi\ i $$

Thank you. Doesn't this solution imply that I have to expand and take the square of sinh(z) in the denominator?

IT is: $(z+z^3/3!)^2=z^2+2z^4/3+\dots$

So, I have to truncate the expansion of sinh(z) and then square it (?). I think, if we are to work with expanding sinh(z), the approach I described is more "convenient" for me (especially since I don't feel very comfortable with $O(r^4)$ notations etc. :-) ). This is one reason I asked if there is an alternative way to expanding sinh(z)
